# What Protocol do Terracotta and Quartz Scheduler Nodes use?

Tags: java, protocols, quartz-scheduler, terracotta, application-layer

I am using Quartz Scheduler with TerracottaJobStore and I'm trying to figure out which protocol the Scheduler Nodes and Server use to communicate.

To explain it another way, in a web application setup, the Browser (client) communicates with Apache (server) with HTTP or HTTPS over TCP/IP. What is the equivalent for Quartz and Terracotta?

I know Quartz Scheduler and Terracotta Server use TCP/IP, but is there an application layer protocol like HTTP also being used?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try referring the question to Terracotta? If you are using the TerracottaJobStore that means you (or your organization) are a paying customer!

Comment: I am now researching into the tool, would you care to share your experience using it offline?